# lidR plot large LAS crashes RStudio

Tags: r, las, lidr, plot

I'm trying to plot a large LAS (9GB, 269,671,586 points) using plot in the lidR library. (RStudio version 2022.07.2 Build 576, R version 4.2.2, lidR version 4.0.1)

I have plotted smaller LAS successfully but with the large las the plot (rgl) window opens but then RStudio crashes. There are no errors sent to the console that I can see.

I have tried using `options(rgl.debug=TRUE)` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72055992/rgl-crashes-r-4-2-0-in-rstudio) but it has no effect. `las_check` returns no significant problems with the las. I'm just using `plot(las)` to do the plotting.

I'm guessing that it's the size of the LAS that is the problem but I'm not sure. How can I either plot a large las with lidR (if that is likely to be the problem) or get a detailed output for debugging?

Comment: `rgl` definitively can't handle such a large file.

Comment: Okay. I remember there being another plotting system a while ago but I've searched and can't see any reference to it any more and I can't quite remember what it was called. Is there any other plotting option in R that I can use?

Comment: There is https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidRviewer but I recommend you to use a real point cloud viewer from another software.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, don't use R for viewing large point clouds.